# Android: FFmpeg taking high memory/cpu usage causing crash

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I compiled ffmpeg for android, enabled mediacodec and jni. its works but when I merge HD video 60fps, its crash the app. this ffmpeg cmd I am using.

```
[-y, -benchmark, -ss, 0.0, -t, 11.541, -i, VID_HD.mp4, -filter_complex, [0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=1080.0:1920.0:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1080:1920:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2:color=#000000, -c:v, libx264, -c:a, aac, -ac, 2, -ar, 44100, -preset, ultrafast, -strict, -2, VID_HD.ts]
```

Sometimes I get these error for same cmds, but when I rerun, it works and sometimes these, if I rerun 3-4 times its restart the app. maybe because of memory is not cleaning. Help me here.

```
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height

VideoKit:Error: Failed to inject frame into filter network: Out of memory

VideoKit:Error: Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
```

I need help in cleaning FFmpeg also when execution finished and I call my run(FFmpeg cmds) method for next video encoding it restart the app, I am suspecting because of memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing my code, I found I am not calling `exit_program()` at the end of run method `ffmpeg_main_entry()` which is calling `exit_program()` , and this method registered `ffmpeg_clenup()` by reference `program_exit`.  After writing that one line code `exit_program()`, it works, but still testing.